# average of derivative over function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, average, slope

I have found this construction in calculus that i found useful. I wanted to find the average of the derivative over a real function from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. I started with this intuitive integral:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow \infty}{1\over 2h}\int_{-h}^{h}f^{'}(x)dx$$
And i simplified it to this:
$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow \infty}{f(h)-f(-h)\over 2h}=T[f(x)]$$
**Is there any official name for this idea, or is it just another construction?**
It's simply the application of the formula for slope with limits approaching infinity.
$$m={y_2-y_1\over x_2-x_1}$$

Here are some properties i have found with this construction.
$$T[f(x)+g(x)]=T[f(x)]+T[g(x)]$$
$$f(-x)=f(x)\Rightarrow T[f(x)]=0$$
$$T[c_0x^0+c_1x^1+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+...]=T[c_1x^1+c_3x^3+c_5x^5+...]$$

Comment: Be careful with where this operator is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a non-decreasing function this is the same as 'total variation', and is the most similar functional I have come across.

Edit: your functional is not equal to the total variation in any case, but these seem to be related ideas

Comment: The identity function $f(x)=x$ is non-decreasing, its total variation is infinity but the average as defined here is 1. I don't believe that the average is related to total variation.

Comment: Oh yeah... Oops